# Help with modeling

Tags: modeling

I've been modeling the sentry turret from the Portal game and I'm struggling on creating a part of the mesh. Here's a small montage I made of what I want to do:
[image: The images in the top are reference and the bottom ones are mine]

I'd like to learn how to model it :D

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use descriptive titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great modifier for getting objects to wrap around curved surfaces is the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.

Take a flat plane and apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to it with the turret wall as a target. This essentially flattens it onto the inner wall of the turret. Take note, you will need to subdivide the plane so that the *Shrinkwrap* modifier can bend the mesh.

From there, you can add a small *Solidify* modifier so that it sticks out a bit.